# How to report failures of automated tests with different severity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, automated-tests, circleci

How can I make a distinction between critical tests that fail (and that should be addressed immediately) vs. tests that fail, but aren't too critical (eg. a tab-view with the wrong default tab open)? It seems like most services (I am using CircleCI) only show you red or green.

I feel like I need some intermediate "orange" color in addition to the green and red colors. Is there any add-on or trick that could help us make the distinction between critical test failures and acceptable ones? (For example with annotations @non-critical?)

I am using Cucumber for testing a Ruby on Rails application.

EDIT

Here are two ways that could make sense (feel free to suggest other approaches):

- One single build alert that is not just "green" or "red" but could be "yellow/orange" depending on which tests fail
- Many builds, that can only be green or red, but that would be labeled

  > Build of "critical tests" succeeded with 0 errors (green)
  >
  > Build of "non-critical" tests failed with 10 errors (red)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way would be to separate the execution between critical and non critical features. It would be quicker to detect a critical failure and you'd be able to run them more often.

To run the critical features **tagged** with `@critical` :

```
cucumber --tags @critical
```

To run the non critical features **not tagged** with `@critical` :

```
cucumber --tags ~@critical
```

Documentation: 
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags

Comment: This makes sense, but I got the impression from the OP that he is looking for a way to further separate the output of a CI test run, in terms of visual feedback. Running the tests in two passes, one for critical and one for non-critical, is a great firs step. Now how to change the color of non-critical failures. no idea.

Comment: The business guys in my team like to have visual feedback on what the devs are doing. My CircleCI build results are sent to a slack channel. SO you would suggest maybe using something like [CircleCI-matrix](https://github.com/michaelcontento/circleci-matrix) to trigger several builds corresponding to sets of tags ?

Comment: @Cyril Duchon-Doris, I've never used circleci, but from what I've seen, it's possible to execute multiple tests for a single build. Then, aggregate the results with a simple script and push the report to you slack channel.

Comment: Ah yes I see what you mean now. I suppose this won't just be a "simple script", as I still need to parse build artifacts, etc. But I will probably be able to find examples of the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend against having tests that are 'non-critical'. A binary pass/fail result is simple to manage: a suite either passes and all is well, or it fails and needs to be fixed. Whenever I've seen a test suite divided into levels of importance, the team immediately began paying attention only to the tests in the highest-importance group and more of the less-important tests were allowed to fail.

Instead, if a test isn't considered important enough to be fixed, delete it. Even better, if a feature isn't considered important enough to be tested, remove or simplify it so there is nothing to test.

Note that both the product owner and developers get to have input on what's important enough to be fixed. For example, if the developers have a standard of 100% code coverage and a test is the only test that provides some of that coverage, the developers would be right to insist that the test be kept passing even if the feature that it tests isn't considered critical by the product owner. Although that would then suggest that the feature should be removed or simplified so that the test wouldn't be needed by developers either.

Comment: While that may be nice for already well established applications, I am coding for a startup in a somewhat agile environment, and we are deliberately leaving broken tests due to time constraints (in fact we are adding automated tests to an already existing application). We DO want to "pay attention only to highest-importance tests". We can afford some broken features, but it would be bad if the billing system went down ^^"

Comment: All the more reason to decide which tests are critical and which not and permanently disable (or don't write) the non-critical ones.